# Section Underline (hr)

Tags: html, css

I created an image and I wanted to use that as an hr for a page. When it's uploaded it is justified all the way to the left. I want it to be centered, under the heading. This is my css code:

```
.section-underline {
     height: 35px !important;
     display: block;
     background-image:url("http://s18.postimg.org/rhqgsx8bp/underline.png") !important;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     border: 0;
}
```

This is a link to the page I'm working on: http://fortunabakery.getbento.com/

and a screenshot: [underline and header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7bNV.png)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, set an explicit `width` and then apply `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` and it will be centered!

In your case, that means:

```css
.section-underline {
  width: 133px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

[image: Example of changes showing success]

Comment: this is the answer

Answer (score 0):

in your CSS, use `background-position: center center`